# Requirejs and browser memory management

Tags: javascript, optimization, browser, requirejs

I am starting to work with requirejs for the first time and it occurred to me that the way I am using it might be bad for browser performance.  Here is the situation:

The nature of my application is such that the set of javascript modules that I need to load must be decided at run-time.  Based on user input, I have to load any subset of the ten js files 1.js...10.js.  I do this loading with requirejs.  The issue comes in when writing 1.js...10.js: they all use requirejs to load React.  My understanding is that each of the React modules that is loaded will be a new object in the browser's memory.  With just a few files, it is much of a concernt.  However, I am curious about scaling this up to the case where there are 100 of these dynamically loaded javascript files, should I worry about this memory issue (especially on, say, a mobile browser)?  This scaling up  is not necessarily something that will happen, so treat this as a thought experiment for my edification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic rule with RequireJS is that a module is created once and only once. It is created upon first being requested and all subsequent requests get the same copy of the module.

The rule does not apply if:

1. You create [contexts](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion) in addition to the default one. You have to create contexts explicitly in the configuration you pass to `requirejs.config` so if you are not creating contexts now, then you are only using the default context. If you request the same module in two different contexts, it will be loaded twice.
2. If you use [`requirejs.undef`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef). If you undefine a module and require it again, then it will be created anew.

Now what happens if you call functions that are specific to 3rd party libraries depends on these libraries. If a library has, for instance, an `init()` function that is called a dozen times it may allocate new structures each time it is called. You have to determine this by reading the documentation of the library or reading the source code.